# Is there a way to extract a column value and use it in a where clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So i have this table let's call it table A. Table A contains a column that has a snippet of sql code. For example it may have a string that says "location = 'Paris'". My issue is trying to have a where statement that extracts this value and uses it in the where clause.

```
select *
from Table B
where (select location from table A) and day='Monday'
```

The issue with this snippet is that the value returned is a string not a boolean and BQ does not allow the and operator for strings and boolean.

**The desired result would return all rows where the day is Monday and the location is Paris**

P.S. this is in BigQuery

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguos, do you have a column _location_  or do you have a column containing _SQL_ text like _**location = 'Paris'**_  in _Table A_. If its just _location_   then you can use **in** clause with subquery from Table A else use below explanation from Mikhail.

Comment: @gmatharu it is the former the column contains the value "location='Paris'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below example as an example of how to achieve it

```
execute immediate '''
select *
from tableB t
where ''' || (select location from tableA)
```

You can test above using below script with simplified/dummy data

```
create temp table tableA as (
  select "location = 'Paris'" location
);
create temp table tableB as (
  select 1 id, 'LA' location union all 
  select 2, 'NY' union all 
  select 3, 'Paris'
);
execute immediate '''
select *
from tableB t
where ''' || (select location from tableA)
```

with below output

[image]

Comment: wow fantastic! thank you. in BQ what is 'execute immediate' doing that makes this query work?

Comment: check this out  - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate

Comment: is there a way to use this (or a similar query) but in Tableau custom SQL?